# Performance of accessing dataSet fields using Field-names instead of indexes

Tags: performance, delphi, dataset

Is the performance negligible?

For example,

```
myQuery.FieldbyName("MyField").AsString;
myQuery.Fields[0].AsString;
```

Cases: 
Table with a decent number of fields, say > 50 fields

Accessing large resultsets, say > 100,000 rows

Is the readability benefit of field names worth the performance decrease?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an interesting post by François Gaillard about [FieldByName performance issues](http://fgaillard.com/2010/11/fieldbyname-findfield-too-convenient-to-be-honest/).

Comment: I wish there was a code style checker tool for inefficient code like that in the Delphi IDE (similar to FxCop) ...

Comment: There is CodeHealer, but I never used it: http://www.socksoftware.com/codehealer.php

Answer (score 4):

The performance **may not** be negligible, depending on how often you access the field by name. If you use it for every field and every row you may notice a performance decrease (see for example http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/74559). To mantain readability yet improve performance you could:

1. Use the <strike>['FieldName'] or</strike> FieldByName() syntax only once, and store a reference to the field in a variable.
2. Use <strike>"static"</strike> persistent field declaration, right-clicking the dataset, select Field Editor and adding needed fields. It will declare the proper TField descendant, and let you assign a name.

Also the AsXXXXX calls may be slower than using a TField descendant native Value property.

Comment: Are you sure that `.Value` is faster than `.As[Type]`?  IIRC, `.Value` is a variant type property, while `.As[Type]` is a more efficient type-specific property.  `.Value` is more convenient.

Comment: BTW: "Persistent fields" is the term you are looking for... ;-)

Comment: The ['Fieldname'] syntax does not return the field but the field's value, so it cannot be used to store a reference to the field.

Comment: @Jørn: Value is of the native type in TField descendants. However, performance depends on how it is internally implemented, it could call the same function of the field's type AsXXXX (IIRC VCL does this) or viceversa (other libraries work that way). You're right "persistent" is the correct term.
@dummzeuch: correct, it's a syntax I never use and forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found FieldByName to be noticeable slower.

I normally access the database through an intermediate layer, that access entire records from the same table alot of times. On creation of that layer I assign the index of each field to an variable. I then use the variables for later access, to still have readable code.

```
ADODataSet.CommandText := 'select * from [TABLE] where 1 = 0'; //table layout
ADODataSet.Open;
ADODataSet.GetFieldNames(List);
varMyField := List.IndexOf('MyField');
```

Comment: In this case it is probably faster to store a reference to the TField object rather than an its index.